# Output file not created when running server under IMR

Tags: c++, corba

I have a very simple CORBA code.  It has one simple routine to write out a message to a file.  The code runs fine if I bring up the server manually.
The output file would be created as expected.  If I add the server 
to the IMR and let the IMR takes care of start up, the code won't write out the out file.  Can someone tell me what is happening and how to fix it ?

```
void
Hello_impl::say_hello() throw (CORBA::SystemException)
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   char* msg = strdup ("Hello from this world to the next");

   ofstream out;
   out.open ("./mydata2.txt", std::ios::out);
   out << msg;
   out.close();
}
```

Here is the server code.

```
run (CORBA::ORB_ptr orb)
{
   CORBA::Object_var poaObj =
      orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");

   PortableServer::POA_var rootPoa =
      PortableServer::POA::_narrow(poaObj);

   PortableServer::POAManager_var manager =
      rootPoa->the_POAManager();

   CORBA::PolicyList policyList(2);
   policyList.length(2);

   policyList[0] = rootPoa->create_lifespan_policy(
      PortableServer::PERSISTENT);

   policyList[1] = rootPoa->create_id_assignment_policy(
      PortableServer::USER_ID);

   PortableServer::POA_var helloPOA =
      rootPoa->create_POA ("hello", manager, policyList);

   CORBA::PolicyList policyList;

   PortableServer::POA_var helloPOA =
      rootPoa->create_POA ("hello", manager, policyList);

   Hello_impl* helloImpl = new Hello_impl(helloPOA);
   PortableServer::ServantBase_var servant = helloImpl;

   PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid =
      PortableServer::string_to_ObjectId("hello");

   helloPOA->activate_object_with_id (oid, servant);
   Hello_var hello = helloImpl->_this();

   CORBA::String_var s = orb->object_to_string(hello);
   const char* refFile = "/tmp/Hello.ref";
   ofstream out (refFile);
   out << s << endl;
   out.close();
}
```

Comment: I found out the problem.  Apparently CORBA did not like the relative path name ./mydata2.txt.  After I specify the complete path name, it works.

Comment: Probably the working directory is different then you expect and the file is put somewhere else on disk (probably in the directory of the ImR executable)